# Why have I not received the Altruist badge yet?

Tags: support, bounties, bounty-badges

I placed a bounty on someone else's question about a week ago, but I haven't earned the Altruist badge yet. Is this normal?

I tried to find the question to post it here, but I can't work out how to find someone else's question that I put a bounty on!

However, I don't think it's received any answers since I started the bounty. Would this be why I haven't got the badge yet?

Comment: Sounds like you're not sufficiently disinterested :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to **award** the bounty to get the *Altruist* badge.

You can find your question in the **Featured** questions section of whatever tag you placed it under.

**Edit:**

Act quickly to award your altruistic bounty; it ends tomorrow and has five answers:

- [How to make two android devices to communicate through TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526830/how-to-make-two-android-devices-to-communicate-through-tcp)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got the Investor on May 17th for *placing* the bounty.  To get the Altruist, you must manually award the bounty to a user that you select(the badge isn't earned if the system automatically gives half to the highest votegetter (with a score of +2 or more) at the end of the bounty period).  ["Rules and restrictions may apply"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).